# Highcharts: how to bring pop-up boxes above the stock-tools menu?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/delux123/c9tj1ywa/24/) code from where we can see how moving the mouse over the chart is creating pop-up boxes. The issue for me is the case when these pop-up boxes are shown above the [stock-tools](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/stock-tools) menu and it results like

[image]

So is there any way how can I bring the pop-up boxes before the stock-tools, so that I can avoid the case which I captured above?
I tried with changing the `z-index` property of some classes (which I detected dynamically), but was not able to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable `outside` property and set `z-index` for a tooltip container with a value greater than 10:

```
tooltip: {
  outside: true
}
```

CSS:

```
.highcharts-tooltip-container {
    z-index: 10 !important;
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3m2wue7b/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/tooltip.outside